# PHP convert date notation

Tags: php, date

Hope this one is simple:

In some settings i get the desired date notation as: `d.m.Y`.
When working with some XML stuff i need the notation as following: `%d.%m.%Y`.

Is there a way to convert those into each other? I dont need to convert dates into different notations but the notation itself.

OK. So here an example:

```
$dateformat = $config->dateformat; // "d.m.Y"
...
$form->setFieldAttribute('date', 'format', '%d.%m.%Y');  // this is where i cannot use $config->dateformat
```

The notation in the settings can change and that needs to reflect on the other notation. Is there some function for that or do i need to code something?

Thanks!

Comment: It is not totally clear to me what you are asking. Can you provide a couple of simple examples

Comment: updated question

Comment: You say you have **d.m.Y** and want **%d.%m.%Y**. That's the same thing.

Comment: what do you mean by "same thing"? i can't write `$form->setFieldAttribute('date', 'format', 'd.m.Y');`

Comment: Okay, I got it, you don't want to change the format of your dates but the string in which your format is stored.

Comment: yes, i want to convert one notation (d.m.Y) into another (%d.%m.%Y).

Answer (score 0):

You need to code something. And the code might not work in all cases.
Example code for doing this the simple way (but problem isn't simple):

```
$divider = ".";  
$df1 = "%d.%m.%Y";
$df2 = str_replace("%", "", $df1);
$df3 = substr(str_replace($divider,"$divider%",($divider.$df2)), 1);

echo "$df1<br>";
echo "$df2<br>";
echo "$df3<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dateformat = '%' . implode('.%', explode('.', $dateformat));
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because %M != M. See http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php and http://php.net/manual/de/function.strftime.php

Comment: Like i said, the config notation is free to be configured. I could happen someone writes `d.M.Y`

Comment: OK. that was the question, if maybe there is something to get this done. I imagine i'm not the only one needing this. Thanks for your time!

Comment: "The notation in the settings can change"

Comment: "M" is not an incorrect symbol. You code was very static and i said that all notations can happen. don't bother.